# Why does a binomial glm give negative predictions?

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model, binomial-distribution

I'm using count data in quite a simple way, but I cannot understand how a binomial glm can return negative predictions

example code, where count of successes increases with responce variable:

```
    suc=c(1:10)
    fail=c(10:1)
    predict(glm(cbind(suc,fail)~c(1:10),family=binomial))
```

which results in:

```
    -1.9974174 -1.5535469 -1.1096763 -0.6658058 -0.2219353  0.2219353  0.6658058 1.1096763  1.5535469  1.9974174
```

I don't understand this: how can a binomial model give these predictions? It should be integer positive predictions, no?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Assuming that you are using the `predict.glm()` from the `stats` package.

A quote from the manual, under the entry explaining the type parameter:

> Thus for a default binomial model the default predictions are of log-odds
>             (probabilities on logit scale) and ‘type = "response"’ gives
>             the predicted probabilities.

So instead, try the following:

```
predict(glm(cbind(suc,fail)~c(1:10),family=binomial), type="response")
```